# Find the derivative $\frac{dx}{dy}$ if $y=\sqrt{x^{3 }}-\ \frac{5}{x}+\ \frac{\pi}{2}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

So for this question, I started with getting the derivative derivative of $y$ with respect to $x$ which is
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{3}{2}\sqrt x +5x^{-2}$$

Which works out fine but when it comes to finding the derivative of $x$ with respect to $y$, I'm very confused on what to do next.

Comment: The expression that you have stated is the derivative of $y$ with respect to $x$.

Comment: Note that $\dfrac{dx}{dy}=\dfrac{1}{\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)}$.

Comment: Your expression for $dy/dx$ is incorrect.

Comment: @Gary How so? Could you please explain it to me?

Comment: @Icy: The derivative of $\sqrt{x^3}$ is not $\frac{1}{3}x^{-2/3}$. You should write $\sqrt{x^3}$ as $\left(x^3\right)^{1/2}=x^{3/2}$. Then, use the power rule.

Comment: General comment targeting the responding answers/comments [1] The cited formula only applies if the inverse function exists.  Therefore, there should be some discussion of in what intervals $f(x)$ is either strictly increasing or strictly decreasing.  [2] Just as $\frac{dy}{dx}$ has been expressed solely in terms of $(x)$, the real challenge is to express $\frac{dx}{dy}$ solely in terms of $(y)$, *if possible*.

Answer (score 1):

Note that:
$$\frac{dx}{dy}=\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^{-1}=\cfrac{1}{\cfrac{dy}{dx}}$$
However, be careful as the same is not true for higher derivatives or partial derivatives

Comment: See my comment following the original question.

Answer (score 0):

With $dx/dy$ you are seeking reciprocal of its derivative. You can also look upon it as the slope of the inverse function at this point.So

$$\dfrac{dx}{dy}=\dfrac{1}{(\frac32) x^{\frac12}+ \dfrac{5}{x^2}}$$
where the denominator is the direct $dy/dx$.

Comment: See my comment following the original question.